# Android show one time page

Tags: android

in my android application i designed a terms of use page, I want to show this page until the accept button is clicked. if it is clicked it will not be shown on the app. How can I do that? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy. Use a Button with an onClickListener. Onec its clicked write a simple var to the sharedpreferences like in this sample:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("terms_accepted", true);
```

editor.commit();

As soon as your Main Activity starts check in onCreate if the terms has been accepted by validating the sharedpferences. Show it if the var is false or not there by using this for example:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
boolean accepted = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("terms_accepted", false);

if (accepted) { ... run your code to spawn the terms dialog ... }
```

Thats it. No magic.